# Why am I getting this error when loading weights?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

```
# Load the hdf5 files
resnet50 = h5py.File('/content/RestNet 50 best_model.hdf5', 'r')
ourmodel = h5py.File('/content/best_model.hdf5', 'r')
resnet152 = h5py.File('/content/best_model_4.hdf5', 'r')

# Get the predictions from each model
predictions1 = resnet50.predict(images)
predictions2 = ourmodel.predict(images)
predictions3 = resnet152.predict(images)

# Combine the predictions using a majority vote
predictions = np.array([predictions1, predictions2, predictions3])
predictions = np.mean(predictions, axis=0)
print(predictions)
```

The error is

OSError: Unable to open file (truncated file: eof = 225443840, sblock->base_addr = 0, stored_eof = 245806944)

Comment: you should load a model using `tf.keras.models.load_model` not as `h5py.File`

Comment: @V.M That is not what the question is about, the question is why there is an error.

Comment: The problem is that one of these HDF5 files is corrupted or incomplete (like a partial download), where did you get them from?

Comment: @V.M So I can just load models like that and it should run, the rest of the code is fine, no?

Comment: the rest of the lines are not right. You should use `load_model` functionality to load the model. That will give the `predict` method, that you can use to predict the images.

Comment: You will get the same error with load_model if you do not fix the problem with these weight files

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy i have 3 files, resnet152, resnet50 and my own model ran on 12 epochs if I run them again, will that work? I might have ran resnet50 till 20 by mistake.

Comment: Impossible to say, as you did not say where these weight files came from.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy I saved these files myself when I ran my Resnet152 and 50 models.

Answer (score 0):

> OSError: Unable to open file (truncated file: eof = 225443840,
> sblock->base_addr = 0, stored_eof = 245806944)

That means your file is corrupted. It is expected to be 245806944 bytes, but after reading 225443840 bytes it just ends. The only option is to re-download it or find a file, that was not corrupted. This often happens, if your connection breaks while downloading or if you trained it on your own, your process was stopped before it could finish writing the file to your disk.